# partprobe displays 'msdos'

Tags: partition

Why is `partprobe -s` displaying 'msdos', when I run it in Linux?

Answer (score 3):

It says that because that's one of the common names for that type of partition table ([MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_Boot_Record) based partitioning) that is still widely used on PCs.
This scheme dates back to 1983 and IBM PC DOS according to Wikipedia, and the name "DOS partitions" has stuck since then.

Comment: Hey thank for ur ans I m beginner can u Plz elaborate

Comment: There's nothing more to it. That's one of the names given to MBR partitioning which is what you are using on your machine. There's a link in my post to the relevant Wikipedia page, and that links to other partitioning schemes.